# based on the credentials i have to navigate to project A or Project B

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 3 projects namely login, A, B

based on the credentials in project login i have to navigate to project A or Project B

it is windows form app written in c#

any one who knows how to achieve above statement or any experience such as above of yours??

please share.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 different dll's for A & B and refer them in login project.
Based on the credentials you could call different functionalities of different dll's

```
                                  **OR**
```

You can deploy all 3 applications as different executables. After getting credentials from login.exe, call A.exe or B.exe accordingly and exit from login.exe as like,

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName   = "A.exe"; //Or B.exe
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create three assemblies - one for the login screen (entry method Main()) and one for each project. After the credentials has been entered I would decide which project should be loaded and dynamically load the appropriate assembly. Both project assembly should implement a common interface to specify how to start your actions.